# Typescript cant find declaration file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

Im not sure why but typescript cannot find my declaration file even though I have one. Can anyone see why this is?

My project structure:

```
scr
  - main.ts
  - dec.d.ts

str-utils
  - index.js
```

The import:

```
import {strReverse, strToLower} from '../str-utils/index.js'
```

My declaration file (dec.d.ts):

```
declare module "str-utils"
```

My typescript config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "src/dec.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The general rule for the name of `declare module "{name}"` is that it should be the same name you would use to import the module. So, in this case, `declare module '../str-utils/index.js'`. But this will not work because `declare module "{name}"` doesn't work for relative paths. You have two options to solve this issue:

**1. Making the import non-relative:**

You modify the tsconfig to make `str-utils` available without a relative import.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // other options
    "paths": {
      "string-utils": ["./str-utils/index.js"]
    },
  },
  // other options
}
```

Now you can import `str-utils` via `import {strReverse, strToLower} from 'str-utils'` and thus, your module declaration works.

**2. Moving the declaration file into the `str-utils` folder**

First, you need to remove `declare module "str-utils"` from your declaration file. It should look something like this:

```
// no wrapping declare module "name" anymore
export function strReverse(arg: string): string;

export function strToLower(arg: string): string;
```

Then you need to rename the declaration file name to match the file name of the module you want to augment. In this example, we want to augment `index.js`, so the type declaration's file name should be `index.d.ts`. Your folder structure should look like that for this approach:

```
src
  - main.ts
  
str-utils
  - index.d.ts
  - index.js
```